# Extract lines based on a column matching one of multiple values

Tags: bash, awk, filter, grep, col

I have some files containing the following data:

```
 160-68 160 68 B-A 0011 3.80247
 160-68 160 68 B-A 0022 3.73454
 160-69 160 69 B-A 0088 2.76641
 160-69 160 69 B-A 0022 3.54446
 160-69 160 69 B-A 0088 4.24609
 160-69 160 69 B-A 0011 3.97644
 160-69 160 69 B-A 0021 1.82292
```

I need to extract lines having any of values (that can be negative: ex -12222) in an array in the 5th column.

Output with [0088, 0021]:

```
160-69 160 69 B-A 0088 2.76641
160-69 160 69 B-A 0088 4.24609
160-69 160 69 B-A 0021 1.82292
```

I'm currently doing this with Ruby, but is there a way to do it faster with Bash?

Thanks.

Comment: Bash is not really optimized for speed; unless you're doing it *poorly* with Ruby, it's unlikely that you'll get a speed improvement by switching to Bash.

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight: as is often the case, when people tag a question (just) [tag:bash] or ask for a "Bash solution", they don't actually mean a _pure_ Bash solution; rather, they mean: a solution based on _utilities that can be called from Bash_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash is unlikely to be faster than ruby: bash is generally pretty slow. I'd pick awk or perl

```
awk -v values="0088 0021" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(values, a)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) b[a[i]]=1
    }
    $5 in b
' file
```

```
perl -ane 'BEGIN {%v = ("0088"=>1, "0021"=>1)} print if $v{$F[4]}' file
```

Comment: I'm interested - Is there a different between your `awk` solution and this `awk '$5 == "0021" || $5 == "0088"' file` ? Thanks :-)

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: For the sample input at hand there is no difference, but the Awk command in this answer offers a _generic_ solution: the desired values are passed as _arguments_ (as Awk variables via `-v`) rather than being hard-coded into the script, and the script supports a _variable_ number of arguments.

Comment: No. It's just a different method to get the keys into the awk script. Depends on how many there are and whe6ther the OP wants to hardcode them into the awk script or elsewhere

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=n; i++)` can just be `for (i in a)` so then you also don't need the `n=` in `n = split(values, a)` and finally `b[a[i]]=1` doesn't need the assignment, just `b[a[i]]` is all you need, so the BEGIN section can just be `split(values, a); for (i in a) b[a[i]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an egrep-based solution.

Suppose the array of special values is given as a simple CSV string, e.g.

```
A="0088,0021"
```

Then the following invocation of egrep will select the desired lines:

```
egrep "( [^ ]+){3} ($(tr , '|' <<< "$A")) "
```

In practice, it would probably be better to modify the regex above to make it less brittle with respect to the input format.

If the elements of the array ($A) contain characters that are special to egrep (such as square brackets, parentheses, etc.), then some care will be required to escape them.  This can be done programatically, e.g.

```
A=$(sed 's/[]\.|$(){}?+*^]/\\&/g' <<< "$A")
```

See also the comment below.

Comment: With all due humility I suggest [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375) as the most robust - and simpler - way to escape a literal for use in a regex; in short: `sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$varContainingLiteralToEscape"`. In addition, you'll still need double-quoting around the command substitution, as suggested earlier.

Comment: mklement0 - Thanks for your suggestions, which I've incorporated into the revised answer as you'll see.  Please note that (a) my post had originally assumed that $A would be as the OP seemed to describe (i.e., positive or negative decimal integers); and (b) I mentioned the link to the SO page because it included at least one response illustrating how sed can be used to escape special characters in the REGEX component of `sed 's/REGEX/TO/'`.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution

```
     #!/bin/bash
     for i in "$@"
         do 
         while read column
         do
            arr=(${column})
            if [ ${arr[4]} = $i ]
            then
                echo $column
            fi
         done < input.txt
    done
```

where input.txt is data file and you call this script as
./scriptname  0088 0021